# if statements in return methods

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

I am a beginner with very very basic knowledge in c#.

How can i write a return method with an `if` statement? for example: i have to calculate the cost to fill up a pool and choose the cheapest alternative. My options are to use the hosepipe method or fire engine method.

Using the hosepipe method: if the size of the pool < 11, then the cost will be `3.20 * 32`, otherwise it will be `32.00 + (size - 10)`.

using the fire engine method: the cost will be `120.00 + (size* 1.50)`.

This is what I have tried:

```
private  double hosePipeCost(double size)
{
    if (size <= 11) 
    { 
        double answer = size * 3.20;
        return answer;
    }
    else
    {
        32.00 + (size - 10);
    }
}

private  double fireEngineCost(double size)
{
    double answer = (size * 1.50) + 120.00;
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Posting some effort/code instead of the question straight out of the book will get you further.

Comment: the fire engine is never cheaper given those formulas..

Comment: @steve16351 I want to fill my size 11 pool with the hosepipe. Seems the best deal BY FAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can use a regular `if` statement, or you can use a conditional expression.

`if` statment:

```
if( pool.size < 11){
    return 3.20 * 32;
}
else{
    return 120.00 + (pool.size* 1.50)
}
```

conditional expression:

```
return pool.size < 11 ?  3.20 * 32 : 120.00 + (pool.size* 1.50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, It's just a preference but you should store the value on a variable before returning it. Don't do returns while inside the if statement.

```
private  double hosePipeCost(double size)
{
    double answer = 0;
    if (size <= 11) 
    { 
        answer = size * 3.20;
    }
    else
    {
        answer = 32.00 + (size - 10);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Or you can use the ternary operator in this case,

```
return size <= 11 ?  size * 3.20 : 32.00 + (size - 10);
```

but then again, if you want readability or incase you have other conditions to satisfy then the if statement is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ternary operator,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) something like this:

```
return ((pool < 11) ? 3.20 * 22 : 32.00 + (size - 10))
```

You got the idea there, adapt it to your case.

Comment: The question specifically asked to use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `else` part code here. You don't need to declare variables here.

Do like below:

```
private  double hosePipeCost(double size)
{
    if (size <= 11) 
        return size * 3.20;       // If the condition is `True`. Returns the value and Ends the execution here.

    return 32.00 + (size - 10);   // If not returns and ends here.
}
```

**OR:**

As a Best practice i would suggest the `Conditional Statement`:

```
private  double hosePipeCost(double size)
{
    return size <= 11 ?  size * 3.20 : 32.00 + (size - 10);
}
```